# onTouchEvent() method gets called over 7 times

Tags: android

Just got into Android development.. Please bear with me.

I created an overridden onTouchEvent function. Every time I touch somewhere inside my app, I expect it to run the function twice. Instead, the function runs random number of times. Some times 7, other times 12. I am just wondering if this is normal?

This is my code if anyone is curious..

```
package com.jojocoder.subhunter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numberHorizontalPixels;
    int numberVerticalPixels;
    int blockSize;
    int gridWidth = 40;
    int gridHeight;
    float horizantalTouched = -100;
    float verticalTouched = -100;
    int subHorizaltalPosition;
    int subVerticalPosition;
    boolean hit = false;
    int shotsTaken;
    int distanceFromSub;
    boolean debugging = true;
    int testcount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        numberHorizontalPixels = size.x;
        numberVerticalPixels = size.y;
        blockSize = numberHorizontalPixels / gridWidth;
        gridHeight = numberVerticalPixels / blockSize;

        Log.d("Debugging","Running OnCreate func");
        newGame();
        draw();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        Log.d("Debugging", "Running newGame func");

    }

    void draw() {
        Log.d("Debugging", "Running draw func");
        printDebuggingText();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        testcount ++;
        Log.d("Debugging", "Running OnTouchEvent func");
        takeShot();

        return true;
    }

    void takeShot() {
        Log.d("Debugging", "Running takeShot func");
        draw();

    }

    void boom() {

    }

    void printDebuggingText() {

        Log.d("numberHorizantalPixels", "" + numberHorizontalPixels);
        Log.d("numberVerticalPixels", "" + numberVerticalPixels);
        Log.d("blockSize", "" + blockSize);
        Log.d("gridWidth", "" + gridWidth);
        Log.d("gridHeight", "" + gridHeight);
        Log.d("horizantalTouched", "" + horizantalTouched);
        Log.d("verticalTouhced", "" + verticalTouched);
        Log.d("subHorizantalPosition", "" + subHorizaltalPosition);
        Log.d("subVerticalPosition", "" + subVerticalPosition);
        Log.d("hit", "" + hit);
        Log.d("shotsTaken", "" + shotsTaken);
        Log.d("debugging", "" + debugging);
        Log.d("distanceFronSub", "" + distanceFromSub);
        Log.d("testcount", "" + testcount);


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add your code please ?

Comment: Done! @KhaledQasem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using onTouchEvent() method to intercept the touch events in an Activity or a View. This method is called several times as the pressure, size, position, etc. of the touch event changes or even when a new finger is put on the touch screen.

Comment: I see! Seems like it's normal... Can someone please test this code and see in the logcat how much is testcount. testcount is the number of times the method ofTouchEvent runs in my code....

Comment: Yes, it's normal.